# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets, jdbc

I m trying to retrieve values from various tables through my query which is as follows,

```
select f.* from     
(select d.DateKey as DK from dbo.DimDate d where d.date between '01/01/2012' and '07/31/2014' ) m

inner join 
(select a. SiteID,a.DateKey,a.Imp,a.OnTarget_Imp,a.Viewable_Imp,b.Plcmnt_Nm from dbo.SocMet_Niel_Fact a left join  dbo.SocMet_NielPlcmnt_Dim b on a.PlcmntID = b.PlcmntID) f        
 on 
 f.DateKey = m.DK where f.SiteID = '25674897'
```

This code runs fine in my SQL Server management Studio but when i run it through my java code it isnt working the same way and throws the Arithmetic overflow Error..

My servlet code for handling this query is

```
      if(type.equals("paid_placement"))
{
    try
    {  
        System.out.println("I m in Paid Placement");
        String site=request.getParameter("site_id");
         System.out.println(site);
         int sid=Integer.parseInt(site);
         System.out.println(sid);
         String start_date=request.getParameter("s_date");
         String end_date=request.getParameter("e_date");
        prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(dbquery.pdd_placement);
        prepStmt.setString(2, start_date);
        prepStmt.setString(3, end_date);
        prepStmt.setInt(1, sid);
        rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
           place_array = new JSONArray();
           while(rs.next())
          {
              json=new JSONObject();
              json.put("placement_name", rs.getString("Plcmnt_Nm"));
              json.put("impressions", rs.getString("Imp"));
              json.put("ontarimp",rs.getString("OnTarget_Imp"));
              json.put("viewable_imp", (int)rs.getInt("Viewable_Imp"));

              place_array.put(json); 

          }
          System.out.println(place_array);
          mainjson=new JSONObject();
          mainjson.put("paid_placement", place_array);
          System.out.println(place_array);


           String responsetojsp=mainjson.toString(); 
           System.out.println(responsetojsp);
           response.setContentType("application/json");
           response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
           response.getWriter().write(responsetojsp);

    }
    catch(NumberFormatException | SQLException | JSONException | IOException e)
    {
         logger.error("Error : " + e);
    }
}
```

and the query in the dbquery page looks like this,

```
 public static String pdd_placement = "select f.* from      \n" +
"   (select d.DateKey as DK from dbo.DimDate d where d.date between ?     and ? ) m\n" +
"   \n" +
"inner join \n" +
"(select a. SiteID,a.DateKey,a.Imp,     a.OnTarget_Imp,a.Viewable_Imp,b.Plcmnt_Nm from dbo.SocMet_Niel_Fact a left     join  dbo.SocMet_NielPlcmnt_Dim b on a.PlcmntID = b.PlcmntID)     f      \n" +
" on \n" +
" f.DateKey = m.DK where f.SiteID = ?";
```

After few comments in this question i have updated my code a little bit i have actually converted my string date values into sql.date values as follows

```
Date s_date;
         s_date = (Date) formatter1.parse(start_date);
         Date e_date;
         e_date = (Date) formatter1.parse(end_date);
         java.sql.Date sqlS_Date;
         sqlS_Date = new java.sql.Date(s_date.getTime());
         java.sql.Date sqlE_Date;
         sqlE_Date = new java.sql.Date(e_date.getTime());
```

but still it throws an error,

> java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

can someone help me with this??

Comment: You really should be using `setDate` rather than `setString`.  You'll want to use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the `String`, or if it's in the right format, you can use the `valueOf` method of `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: @DavidWallace i tried dong wt u said! and it threw another error  Message=java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Comment: Yeah, you need to create a `java.sql.Date` by calling the `getTime()` method of your `java.util.Date`, and passing the return value to the `java.sql.Date` constructor.

Comment: @DavidWallace i think i have done the parsing and i have edited my question with the code snippet where i have parsed the util.Date to sql.Date but still it throws an error stating  java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date can u help me with that?

Comment: OK, which `Date` class do you have an `import` for at the top of your file?

Comment: @DavidWallace import java.util.Date;

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks a tonne for helping me out it finally worked! It was a minor typo that was causing the error!